# I cannot save a value from a select box to a variable

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

At the moment I have the following contact form validation code, and the problem is that when I press the submit button for form validation, it saves only the value of the text fields and not the "Drop Down List" field value that I currently have chosen. I want it to save all fields when there is an error with the form instead of resetting them.

I am using the same method for the select box as for the text fields.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

**PHP**

```
$error    = ''; // error message
$name     = ''; // sender's name
$email    = ''; // sender's email address
$subject  = ''; // subject
$message  = ''; // the message itself
$spamcheck = ''; // Spam check
$test = ''; // test
$telefon = ""; // telefon

if(isset($_POST['send']))
{
$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$subject  = $_POST['subject'];
$message  = $_POST['message'];
$spamcheck = $_POST['spamcheck'];
$test = $_POST['test'];
$telefon = $_POST['telefon'];
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input name="test" type="text" class="detail" id="test" value="<?=$test;?> />

<-- dropdownlist that isn't working --->

<select name="telefon" type="text" class="scroll" id="telefon" value="<?=$telefon;?>>
<option value="-"> </option>
<option value="Epost">E-post </option>
<option value="Telefon">Telefon </option>
</select>
```

[Demo](http://hemsidavisa.site90.net/newmail/).

Comment: =$telefon should be echo $telefon

Comment: @tinyByte you can use short hand echo like this `<?=$telefon;?>` (although the `short_tags` ini setting needs to be turned on)

Comment: thanks for the quick repsonse guys, please be more specific what I have to change ;)

Comment: =$telefon should be echo $telefon, with that you mean the form code should be like this "echo $telefon" instead of value="<?=$telefon;?>?

Comment: @KurtBertil The use of `<?=$foo;?>` is a shorthand expression of `<?php echo $foo;?>` how you currently have it is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply `selected="selected"` attribute to the select **option** not the select input itself.

Since the user would have already posted the form, the "selected" value will be in `$_POST['telefon']`.

This looks a bit messy, but should work:

```
<select name="telefon" type="text" class="scroll" id="telefon">
  <option value="-"> Please Choose&hellip;</option>
  <option value="Epost"<?php echo ($telefon == 'Epost') ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>E-post</option>
  <option value="Telefon"<?php echo ($telefon == 'Telefon') ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Telefon</option>
</select>
```

This will select the value previously posted by the user.

Comment: how do I do that ^^? 1st time I am using this site ;P

Answer (score 0):

Replace Your

```
$telefon = $_POST['telefon'];
```

with this:

```
if ($_POST['telefon']) {
  if (isset($_POST['telefon'])) {
    //echo '1 Row Inserted';
    $telefon = $_POST['telefon'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

it shouldn't be

```
value="<?=$telefon;?>"
```

but for example

```
<option value="Epost" <? if($telefon = 'Epost') echo 'selected'; ?>>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

Comment: This really hasn't explained or answered anything. Plus linking to a [notoriously outdated and incorrect website](http://www.w3fools.com/) won't win you any +1's